# How do zero-conf channels work?

Tags: lightning-network, trust, ln-opening-channels

What zero-conf channels are seems pretty straighforward (correct me if I'm wrong) -- channels that are immediately usable without needed confirmation on the blockchain. These are very useful since Alice can get Bob set up on Lightning without needed to wait for confirmation.

If there are different variants, can you describe how each works,trust assumptions, and possible drawbacks/attack vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand a little bit the answer is already given.

Zero-conf channels, also called turbo channels, are new single-funded channels where the funder gives some or all of their initial funds to the acceptor. Those funds are not secure until the channel open transaction receives a sufficient number of confirmations, so there’s no risk to the acceptor spending some of those funds back through the funder using the standard LN protocol.

For example, Alice has several BTC in an account at Bob’s custodial exchange. Alice asks Bob to open a new channel paying her 1.0 BTC. Because Bob trusts himself not to double-spend the channel he just opened, he can allow Alice to send 0.1 BTC through his node to third-party Carol even before the channel open transaction has received a single confirmation.

[image]

See more here: https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/zero-conf-channels/
See the BOLT RFC here: https://github.com/lightning/bolts/pull/910

ofcs you are trusting the other side so in case of fee spike there are problems

Answer (score 0):

You can have a trustless zero-confirmation channel if it's funded from a 2-of-2 multisignature address and each party has one of the private keys. As far as I can tell, any other setup requires trusting the other party that they don't try to double-spend. Other than that, it works just like a normal channel.

Comment: Except this model is susceptible to fee based attacks like cpfp based tx pinning

Comment: Stumbled upon this question while searching something else. A wiser arshbot knows that cpfp carve out solves this concern.